# Wordpress directory won't open

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpres, and all files from wordpress are in public_html folder. In same public_html folder I have /onlineforms directory, but it won't load using
https://url/onlineforms

There is .htaccess file
Prevent folder browsing
Options All -Indexes

but no changes.

How can I fix this so I will be able to open url/onlineforms/index.php?

Answer (score 0):

you have to hit by file name if you folder has index file you hit `https://url/onlineforms/index.php` or html which file you have load